# There is any run_pending() in APSheduler?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I want to run a specific code every day at 00:00, so I'm using APSheduler but i don't know how to run the missed jobs; in scheduler it was a run_pending() that runs the pendings jobs, i don't know if there are one in APSheduler or if i didn't understand how to use APSheduler.

Here is my code:

```
#Libraries
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler #Import background scheduler
import PREFS
                              
beginDate = datetime.date.today()
beginDate = beginDate.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
prefs = {"kanjiNum": 0, "studyToday": 0, "beginDate": beginDate, "lostKanji": 0}
MainPrefs = PREFS.PREFS(prefs = prefs, filename = "DailyDoseOfKanjis_Prefs") #Defining prefs

####
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start() #initializing scheduler
####

def DailyCheck():
    if int(MainPrefs.ReadPrefs()["studyToday"]) == "1":
        print("You did study")
        MainPrefs.WritePrefs("studyToday", 0)
    elif int(MainPrefs.ReadPrefs()["studyToday"]) == "0":
        print("You didn't study")
        MainPrefs.WritePrefs("lostKanji", int(MainPrefs.ReadPrefs()["lostKanji"]) + 1)

    MainPrefs.WritePrefs("kanjiNum", BeginKanji())

####
scheduler.add_job(lambda: DailyCheck(), 'cron', second = 0, minute = 0, hour = 0,  id = 'check') #Adding daily jobs
scheduler.add_job(lambda: print("yea"), 'cron', second = 0, minute = 51, hour = 8,  id = 'yea') #Adding daily jobs
####
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i gave in with apscheduler and make my own logic with datetime.
Using a library for store preferences i save the a compare date always you close the program and when you open it make a iterate between the difference between today and the compare date, inside the loop execute my daily check and at the end of the program change the compare date to today.

```
import PREFS # To save preferences (https://github.com/Patitotective/PREFS)
import datetime

Mprefs = lambda: {"compareDate": datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}
MainPrefs = PREFS.PREFS(prefs = Mprefs, filename = "Prefs/MainPrefs")

def DailyCheck():
    print("You didn't use me for one long day") #Here your code that you want to execute daily

def RunDailyCheck(): 
    today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
    for i in range(DaysBetween(today, MainPrefs.ReadPrefs()["compareDate"])): #For loop between the difference in days
        DailyCheck()

    MainPrefs.WritePrefs("compareDate", datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")) #Set the compare date to today because it already executed the daily check

# Calculate the days between two dates
def DaysBetween(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y/%m/%d")
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y/%m/%d")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)


RunDailyCheck() #Run the pending checks, if you open the program every day never will execute DailyCheck()
#Your program
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#End of your program

MainPrefs.WritePrefs("compareDate", datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")) #Set the compare date to today when you close the program
```

If you don't understand PREFS library pleas check it's docs: https://github.com/Patitotective/PREFS/wiki.